Will gnome-online-accounts 3.52.0-1 package be included in Ubuntu 24.04?
Will the gnome-online-accounts 3.52.0-1 package ever be included in Ubuntu 24.04? Is there a place where I can request to include this update in the noble repository, the actual version is 3.50?
In the recent version there are many interesting changes.
Overview of changes in 3.52.0

Translation updates:

Bulgarian (Alexander Shopov, twlvnn kraftwerk)
Catalan (Jordi Mas i Hernandez)
Czech (Daniel Rusek)
Danish (Ask Hjorth Larsen)
English (United Kingdom) (Andi Chandler)
French (Irénée THIRION)
Galician (Fran Dieguez)
German (Tim Sabsch)
Indonesian (Andika Triwidada)
Lithuanian (Aurimas Černius)
Polish (Piotr Drąg)
Russian (Artur S0)
Slovak (Dušan Kazik)
Spanish (Daniel)
Swedish (Anders Jonsson)
Turkish (Sabri Ünal)



Overview of changes in 3.51.3

Accessibility fixes and event announcements
Translation updates

Overview of changes in 3.51.2

Adopt a less aggressive notification policy
Translation updates

Overview of changes in 3.51.1

Enable Mail, Calendar & Contacts for Microsoft 365
Improvements to Microsoft 365 setup dialog
Use AdwButtonRow when applicable
Allow overriding dependencies supporting built as a meson wrap
Refactor web browser authentication flow as a discrete task
Improve error reporting and notification for providers
Document configuration files used by the daemon
Correctly save and reset settings for TLS certificate errors

Overview of changes in 3.51.0

Support Mail Autoconfig XML for IMAP/SMTP services
Support SRV lookups for DAV services
Support Linux's KEYRING notification pipe for Kerberos
Ability to restrict which services of a particular account type are available
Add version CLI flag for goa-daemon
Port to AdwDialog and AdwAlertDialog
Accept GtkWidget as a top-level for account setup
Port documentation to gi-docgen
Documentation and manual pages are enabled by default
Fixes for bugs found by Coverity Scan
Fix libsoup error handling
Translation fixes and missing strings
Translation updates


This question is similar to: Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, it won't be backported to 24.04.
The whole point of a "release" in a Debian-based system (like Ubuntu) is that the software versions are frozen for the entire life of the release. All the software is built to rely upon the same set of dependency versions, so changing any of those dependencies may break the whole system. gnome-online-accounts will keep version 3.50 for the entire life of the Ubuntu 24.04 release.
There are a few exception: Bugfix patches, Security patches, and a few critical application like Web browsers. But you are asking to rebuild and re-integrate the entire Gnome stack for this version bump. You may not realize it, but that's an enormous request.
You have some options:
gnome-online-accounts version 3.52 is in Ubuntu 24.10. The Ubuntu developers already did that. You can release-upgrade to Ubuntu 24.10 and start using the version you want today easily. It does mean that you will need to keep release-upgrading every 6 months -- you won't be using LTS anymore.
You can request a backport of the newer package at launchpad.net. It is unlikely that any developer wants to take it on, so that is a bit of a long-shot.
If you have the skills, you can try backporting the package yourself (not for beginners).
